# How to make my main Login frame stay alive when the second frame exiting?

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
package Project;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

 class mydlg extends JDialog
{
    JButton b1,b2;
    JLabel f1;
    public mydlg(JFrame f,String t,boolean b)
    {
        super(f,t,b);
        Container con=getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b1=new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/diamond.gif"));
        f1=new JLabel("Oops!!! You Must Enter the correct Password.");
        b2=new JButton("OK");
        con.setLocation(250, 250);
        con.add(b1);
        con.add(f1);
        con.add(b2);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        b2.setSize(250,250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        con.setBackground(Color.orange);    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);

            }
   });
    }
}


public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
String str;
JTextField lt;
TextField pt;
JButton ba;
JLabel ll,pl,jb1;
public Login() throws Exception
{
Container con=getContentPane();
con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jb1=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/login1.jpg"));
        con.add(jb1);   
con.setBackground(Color.cyan);
//con.setSize(1300, 1400);
lt=new JTextField(20);
pt=new TextField(20);
pt.setEchoChar('*');
ll=new JLabel("Username:");
pl=new JLabel("Password:");
lt.setText("Admin");
ba=new JButton("LOGIN");
        ll.setBounds(45,80,150,30);
        lt.setBounds(140,80,150,30);
        pl.setBounds(45,140,150,30);
        pt.setBounds(140,140,150,30);
        ba.setBounds(140,200,90,30);

con.add(ll);
con.add(lt);
con.add(pl);
con.add(pt);
con.add(ba);
ba.addActionListener(this);
setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    try{

        if(ae.getSource()==ba){
        if(pt.getText().equals("TDJSS")){
        new PrjtMain();
        //rm.setSize(700,700);
        //rm.setVisible(true);

                }
        else{
        mydlg md=new mydlg(this,"Error Login Message",false);
        md.setSize(300,200);
        md.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        md.setVisible(true);
        String cmd = ae.getActionCommand();
        if(cmd.equals("OK"))
        {
        System.exit(0);
        }
        }             
        }

       }catch(Exception ex){}
}

public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
{
Login l=new Login();
l.setSize(350,350);
l.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
l.setTitle("LOGIN");
l.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Hai.... I am successfully running this code.But When i Click The login button without enter the password, It showing an error message. After that When i click the "OK" button, both frames are closing at the same time. I want to make the main login page to be stay.. Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.exit(0);` in the `b2` `ActionListener` will exit the JVM...

Instead, I think you want to use `dispose`

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dispose();
    }
});
```

I would also stop changing the default close operation of the parent window.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you're assuming that this is the result from the dialog, which it isn't...You're referencing the current `ActionEvent` within the context of the `Login` buttons `ActionListener`

```
String cmd = ae.getActionCommand();
if (cmd.equals("OK")) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You should also not ignore exceptions...

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

This is very bad and you shouldn't do it...

You might also want to take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: thanks @MadProgrammer ... Now its working fine.. You're right.. I am a begginer of java. Thatswhy having some troubles to build the simple projects. Surely I will go through the code conventions for the java.. Thanks for your help..

Comment: We all have to start somewhere.  I'd also recommand that you take a read through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). It will save you a lot of frustration in the long run

Comment: wow.. its simply superb.. this is what i searching now.. And I have one more doubt.. Can we place a button or text field or a label in a frame particular place.. also need to arrange all fields manually by giving the values like setLocation(50,50); Its possible or not inside a frame.. Hope you understand what i am telling....

Sorry for the language.. English is my second language.. Please help me..

Comment: Yes it's possible, but highly unrecommended.  You don't control how font rendering works on different platforms and this will affect how your UI looks, but to use appropriate layouts

Comment: Oh.. Oh Now i understood.. Okay I will go thorugh the [linkk](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).. Thank you so much

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444046/how-to-change-the-page-size-in-all-pages-dynamically-in-asp-net]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444046/how-to-change-the-page-size-in-all-pages-dynamically-in-asp-net